# what's difference between 0x61 and \x61 in shellcodes?

Tags: shellcode

Hi what's difference between these two shell code :

```
char code[] = "0xb0,0x01,0x31,0xdb,0xcd,0x80";  
char code[] = "\xb0\x01\x31\xdb\xcd\x80";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No difference...
0x is the hexadecimal presentation but \x is shellcode.
If you wanna use it as shellcode use \x.

Comment: in the some shell codes the first example used but in the some shell codes use the second shell code. I guess is a difference between these two shellcodes. thanks for answer